How to create a production build for a simple React app being deployed using Docker and Node
I am running a simple React app in Docker which runs fine. When I check the logs of the pods it returns a message
2024-08-16 15:58:34 Note that the development build is not optimized.
2024-08-16 15:58:34 To create a production build, use npm run build.

I updated the Dockerfile and included RUN npm run build:${BUILD_ENV} but the warning still returns. I have the Dockerfile below.
# set the base image to build from 
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder

ARG BUILD_ENV

#SET ENV
ENV BUILD_ENV $BUILD_ENV
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy package files
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY . /usr/src/app/
COPY .env.staging /usr/src/app/.env
RUN npm run build:${BUILD_ENV}


EXPOSE 3000
# run the app
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run start:${BUILD_ENV}"]

What am I doing wrong?

Why are you running the dev server after the production build? At that point you just need a static web server, like Nginx (example: https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe/blob/0d519642216193961a0fa85819fc1e3c6bd6e340/Dockerfile).

If you want to deploy a production build using Docker, you need a web server.
When you run
npm run build

it will generate an optimized version of your code, assets, and prepare the application for production deployment. You can use a server like nginx to serve the build version by copying the content of the build files to the HTML folder of nginx. So, to deploy a production build using Docker, you can make your Dockerfile a multistage Dockerfile. It would look like below.
# First Stage:Build the React App
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy package files
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY . /usr/src/app/
COPY .env.staging /usr/src/app/.env
RUN npm run build

#Second stage: use nginx to serve the app
From nginx:alpine

#copy the production build from the first stage to the nginx HTML folder

COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80/tcp

CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

You need to have nginx configuration file, like below.
http {

  include mime.types;

  set_real_ip_from        0.0.0.0/0;
  real_ip_recursive       on;
  real_ip_header          X-Forward-For;
  limit_req_zone          $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /proxy;
    limit_req zone=mylimit burst=70 nodelay;

    location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri /index.html;   
        }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}

events {}

To build and run the image use bellow commands:
docker build -t "Image Tag"
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name "Container Name" "Image Tag"

